# Passing the parameters in the request body of an API precisely to get a specific search result

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to use the Flight Availability Search API of Amadeus. In the body section of the post request, I have included the Source, Destination, Date and some other details. I am interested in Emirates airline, so I have included the CarrierCode as 'EK'. But I wish to get the result of EK-1 only (where 001 is the number of the flight), which I am not able to get.

"includedCarrierCodes":"EK"

This is what I have tried. But I am expecting the API to give only EK-001 flights (not all the possible Emirates flights) for this particular date, source and destination.

Answer (score 1):

In [Flight Availability Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/flights/api-doc/flight-availabilities-search/api-reference) (under Amadeus Self-Service APIs), you can't specify the flight number. you can only specify the include/exclude carriers(airlines) to search the availability.

If you are interested in performing advance flight search, it is advised to go to [Enterprise APIs](https://developers.amadeus.com/enterprise/category/air/api/search-and-shopping?catalogId=2).